# Why is this column order in my non-clustered index better for my query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am working on a query for a table that contains movie tickets. The database holds 380k rows. A rows represents a showing of the movie (which cinema, when, how many tickets  and at what price among other things).

I need to compute a few totals for every row: `Admissions Paid`, `Admissions Revenue`, `Admissions Free` and `Total Admissions`.

For a given row `Admissions Paid` is the sum of all tickets for that movie up until that point where `price>0`. The other 3 columns are computed similarly.

I wrote a query and created an index:

```
 SELECT [ID]
      ,[cinema_name]
      ,[movie_title]
      ,[price]
      ,[quantity]
      ,[start_date_time]
      ,* --I need all the columns for reporting
     ,(select SUM(quantity) 
        from [movies] i
        where i.movie_title=o.movie_title
        and i.start_date_time<=o.start_date_time
        and price=0) as [Admissions Free]
        ,(select SUM(quantity) 
        from [movies] i
        where i.movie_title=o.movie_title
        and i.start_date_time<=o.start_date_time
        and price>0) as [Admissions Paid]
        ,(select SUM(quantity*price) 
        from [movies] i
        where i.movie_title=o.movie_title
        and i.start_date_time<=o.start_date_time
        and price>0) as [Admissions Revenue]
        ,(select SUM(quantity) 
        from [movies] i
        where i.movie_title=o.movie_title
        and i.start_date_time<=o.start_date_time) as [Total Admissions]
  FROM [movies] o
```

I created the following index which brought the query time down to 5 minutes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [startdatetime_movietitle_price] ON [dbo].[movies]
(
    [movie_title] ASC,
    [start_date_time] ASC,
    [price] DESC
)
INCLUDE (   [quantity]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

But this index brought the query time down to 1:30:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [startdatetime_movietitle_price] ON [dbo].[movies]
(
    [start_date_time] ASC,
    [movie_title] ASC,
    [price] DESC
)
INCLUDE (   [quantity]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

So my question is: why? From my understanding, it makes more sense to first gather all the movie titles and then look at the start times because there are more start times then there are movies. Distinct `movies`: *51*, distinct `start_date_times`: *8786*

Doesn't the underling B-Tree not cut off more branches if it eliminates the unnecessary `start_date_times` first?

Here are the execution plans:

[image: desc]

[image]

The first picture shows the execution plan for the index with `movie_title` first, the other picture shows `start_date_time` first.

Comment: Could you [provide execution plans](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) for both indexing options?

Comment: Subqueries are too strange... It seems they can be converted to window-type SUM().

Comment: @SabinBio o is the outer table. I edited the question.

Comment: The key is here `Distinct movies: 51, distinct start_date_times: 8786`; some hints could be at the logical reads and in the execution plan(s). For an index, it's very important the first column and how selective it is

Comment: If you have a range scan it works best if the prefix for that range is constant or not exiting. In your case Movie title is very quickly changing, so it would have to do one range check per movie instead of one range seek to lookup every movie below that. But I guess it could go either way, how do the execution plans with statistics look like?

Comment: @vonPryz,  I added the execution plan.

Comment: Could you post a link to the individual plans via [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? You can anonymise information using [Sentry One's Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) if need be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first index does look like a better fit for the query. Please provide the actual execution plans.

I would try using window functions instead of the four correlated subqueries. Or a single correlated subquery (with `OUTER APPLY`) and see which of the two indexes is used.
Both ideas are to coerce the optimizer to use a single index scan to gather the rolling sums instead of 4 (that both your plans do).

It would also be worth checking and comparing the two execution plans, when asking for all the columns and when asking for only the columns in the index:

**using window functions**:

```
-- window functions
SELECT 
    -- m.*,
    movie_title, start_date_time,
    price, quantity,

    SUM(CASE WHEN price = 0 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END)
        OVER
        (PARTITION BY movie_title
         ORDER BY start_date_time
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                   AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS [Admissions Free],
    SUM(CASE WHEN price > 0 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END)
        OVER
        (PARTITION BY movie_title
         ORDER BY start_date_time
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                   AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS [Admissions Paid],
    SUM(CASE WHEN price > 0 THEN quantity * price ELSE 0 END)
        OVER
        (PARTITION BY movie_title
         ORDER BY start_date_time
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                   AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS [Admissions Revenue],
    SUM(quantity)
        OVER
        (PARTITION BY movie_title
         ORDER BY start_date_time
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                   AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS [Total Admissions]
FROM
    [movies] AS m ;
```

*: If there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(movie_title, start_date_time)`, then you could use `ROWS` instead of `RANGE` for the window frames (it's usually more efficient). From the comments, there is no such constraint and there could be many rows with same title and datetime, so `RANGE` is required above.

**using `OUTER APPLY`**:

```
-- using OUTER APPLY
SELECT 
    -- m.*,
    m.movie_title, m.start_date_time,
    m.price, m.quantity,

    c.[Admissions Free],
    c.[Admissions Paid],
    c.[Admissions Revenue],
    c.[Total Admissions]
FROM
    [movies] AS m
    OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT
          SUM(CASE WHEN i.price = 0 THEN i.quantity ELSE 0 END)
              AS [Admissions Free],
          SUM(CASE WHEN i.price > 0 THEN i.quantity ELSE 0 END)
              AS [Admissions Paid],
          SUM(CASE WHEN i.price > 0 THEN i.quantity * i.price ELSE 0 END)
              AS [Admissions Revenue],
          SUM(i.quantity)
              AS [Total Admissions]
      FROM [movies] AS i
      WHERE i.movie_title = o.movie_title
        AND i.start_date_time <= o.start_date_time
    ) AS c ;
```

---

This index may be a little better than the first one:

```
(
    movie_title ASC,
    start_date_time ASC
)
INCLUDE (price, quantity)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed much much faster. Execution time for the first index is 3 sec while it's 4 sec with the second index. I added the execution plans to the post, btw. Can you maybe explain why this is so much faster?

Comment: I tested the query and while it is faster it's not what I need to show. I'll use `Paid Admissions` as an example. Assume there are three shows starting at the same time. Your query computes different `Paid Admissions` for all three columns, but I need them to be the same, namely the sum of all paid admissions at that time. I assume this is because it looks at rows in the OVER part one after the other.

Comment: @dakes oh, I intended to add a note about that. Se the edit. (in short, use `RANGE` not `ROWS`, for the window fames)

Comment: I was torn which answer I should accept because @sepupic s answer actually answers my question, but this one was much more helpful in the long run. SO says "The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.", so I accepted this one. I hope that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **ypercubeᵀᴹ** answer, the query should be rewritten.

> Can you maybe explain why this is so much faster?

The query that use the second `index` is faster only because it's executing in `parallel`. 
Try to add `option(maxdop 1)` and the use of the first index will be faster.